# Memory information

Tags: centos, memory, dmidecode

I have  a server with centos7 , installed  with 8 memory modules. 
I want to know what specific memory is installed on DIMM_A4 for example.
With dmidecode or lshw I get the information on all the banks...
And I want to get information on a specific bank.

How can I do this?

Thanks 
Ben

Comment: You can't just `grep` the output of `lshw`?  Something like `lshw | grep -A9 'bank:4'`?